# Office 2010 doesn't integrate with WSS3?

Tags: wss-3.0, office-integration

On a fresh Windows 7 computer i installed Office 2010 Home & Business. When i try to edit documents in SharePoint, i get this error message:

> 'Edit Document' requires a Windows SharePoint
>   Services-compatible application"

Or if i click on document, it offers me to download the file.

I can't believe that office 2010 isn't compatible with SharePoint 2007. Is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which browser are you using? I have office 2010 and we use a prod WSS 3.0 server at work and we have never had such an issue unless the person is not using IE.

Edit: this is a 64 bit browser issue. All editions of IE 64 bit have only limited support.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526.aspx

Comment: Ahh, using Internet Explorer 9 64-bit and the site is in Local Intranet zone with default settings.

Comment: Uh, oh, it's not that Office 2010 doesn't support SharePoint 2007. On other Windows 7 32bit machine i tried editing a document with Office 2010 Starter and it works! Even the Content Controls work! I didn't even expect that a Starter edition would support SharePoint at all.

Comment: Wow, please document that a little more fully as an answer. Just to be clear - are you saying Starter Edition is the issue?

Comment: no, the Starter edittion works on Windows 7 32 bit but the Home & Business on Windows 7 64 bit doesn't (They are on different PC's). So i guess the issue is with my office installation or perhaps that i'm using Windows 7 64-bit? I don't know, i will still have to look into this issue before documenting it as an answer.

Comment: 64 bit browser has only limited support. I have verified that I get the same error in my environment.

Comment: Ahh, yes, it turns out to be 64-bit problem. Thanks for the answer.